# Composer Symfony 2.5 update not updating directory structure

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I followed this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/nicwortel/0c938aa77c5bd4fde064

I've added the following line in my composer.json, but it's not asking me to upgrade my directory structure. What's going wrong? (The script is present in my vendor directory)

```
"post-update-cmd": [
       "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::defineDirectoryStructure",
]
```

I runned php composer.phar update, but composer didn't ask me to update my dir structure.

Comment: Have you tried re-execute the command ?  `composer run-script post-update-cmd'`

Comment: @Med not working. I did run a little print to see if the script actually runs (which it did). I commented the if statement, which caused the script not to be executed. So it executed now, not a beautiful solution, but it did the job.

Comment: Ok, you should put it as a solution for another one who would face this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is NOT a pretty solution, but it got the job done.

I checked if the script was actually called by Composer by putting a little print statement in the function. The function was indeed called. So I knew the question didn't popped up because the if statement returned false. So I simply deleted the if statement, so the function executed anyways. Not pretty indeed, but it worked.